# Tup variants not building correctly

Tags: c++, tup

I switched from make to tup and am trying to get it to build different variants (debug and production). My source tree looks like this:

```
| .tup
| bin
| build_debug
| | tup.config
| build_default
| | tup.config
| include (headers directory)
| src (source files directory)
| | runs (directory containing additional source files)
| Tupfile
```

And my `Tupfile`:

```
preload bin
preload src
preload src/runs

COMPILER = g++
ifeq (@(DEBUG),y)
FLAGS = -Wall -std=c++17 -O0 -g 
else
FLAGS = -Wall -std=c++17 -O3 -march=native -flto -pipe
endif

: foreach src/*.cc src/runs/*.cc |> $(COMPILER) -c %f -o %o $(FLAGS) |> %B.o
: src/*.o src/runs/*.o |> $(COMPILER) %f -o %o $(FLAGS) |> bin/a.out
```

I want this to create object files within the `src` directories and a binary within the `bin` directories inside the `build*` directories.

When I run `tup`, it will create object files directly inside the `build*` directories (so not inside the `build*/src` directories) and not create any binaries.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**:
When building inside the base directory without any `build*` directories it will create a binary but also place the object files within the base directory and not inside `src`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved it with the help of the tup manual.

%B only expands to the filename, not the filename including the relative path of the file to the basedir, which is why the object files were created in the base directory and the binary could not be generated (I thought it worked because I still had some old object files which had been generated using make).

I rewrote my `Tupfile` to:

```
preload src
preload src/runs

COMPILER = g++
ifeq (@(DEBUG),y)
FLAGS = -Wall -std=c++17 -O0 -g 
else
FLAGS = -Wall -std=c++17 -O3 -march=native -flto -pipe
endif

: foreach src/*.cc |> $(COMPILER) -c %f -o %o $(FLAGS) |> src/%B.o
: foreach src/runs/*.cc |> $(COMPILER) -c %f -o %o $(FLAGS) |> src/runs/%B.o
: src/*.o src/runs/*.o |> $(COMPILER) %f -o %o $(FLAGS) |> bin/a.out
```